# Hashtags: create only one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, tags, relationship

I have this code

```
  private function hashtags($article){
    $htag = '#';
    $arr = explode(" ", $article->description);
    $arrc = count($arr);
    $i = 0;
    $arr_id = [];
    while($i < $arrc){
      if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) === $htag ){
        $hash = Hashtag::firstOrCreate(
            ['name' => $this->hashtagName($arr[$i]), 'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))]
        );

        $article->hashtags()->attach($hash);
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
```

hashtagName is function which modyfiy name of hashtag becouse I use WYSCIWYG editor and sometimes I had a problem with html tags in name column. But it doesn't important here. I tryed solve my problem so I found this code which I can use instead of attach.

```
  if (! $article->hashtags->contains($hash->id)) {
    $article->hashtags()->save($hash);
  }
```

But it doesn't solve my problem. If I store an article with 2 or more this same hashtag, it create this same amount of relationship. If i had uses 3 hashtags in this same article, I would have 3 relationship. Ho i can fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code for relevant relationships please?

Comment: Don't you need to return anything from the function ?

Comment: You didn't explain well your problem :p, do you want to create only one hashTag relationship for all the same hashTags in the article ?

Comment: `$article->hashtags->contains($hash->id)` - sure that contains works here, based on an ID? I think either `contains($this->hashtagName($arr[$i]))`, or `contains('name', $this->hashtagName($arr[$i]))` might make more sense.

Comment: Yes. I want to create one relationship between hashtag and article. For example: I have 3 hashtag: #hashtag x2 and #helloworld . I want to create 2 relationship. I doesn't have create relationship with duplicate hashtag. I don't need return a value becouse tis method only store hashtags and create a relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your implementation is that you check with the id of the hTag.

**Why**

Because if you have two same hTags and you save the first you will get the ID1 then you will attach it, till here there is no issue. But when you save the second same one (which you should not do in the first place) you will get ID2 where ID1 is different from ID2 so this line of check `$article->hashtags->contains($hash->id)` will not find the hTag with the same name.

A possible solution :

```
private function hashtags($article){
    $htag = '#';
    $arr = explode(" ", $article->description);
    $arrc = count($arr);
    $i = 0;
    $arr_id = [];
    while($i < $arrc){
        $hTagName = $this->hashtagName($arr[$i]);

        $exists = Hashtag::whereArticleId($article_id)
                    ->whereName($hTagName)
                    ->exists();

        if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) === $htag && !$exists ){
            $hash = Hashtag::firstOrCreate(
                ['name' => $hTagName, 'slug' => str_slug(ltrim($arr[$i], '#'))]
            );

            $article->hashtags()->attach($hash);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```